# Weird Key mappings on CentOS 8.1 server for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am using ssh'ing from an iMac (11.6.0) with a A1644 keyboard into a CentOS 8.1 server. The Linux server has Visual Studio 1.61.0 installed.  I created a new R code file with in VS and when I type the letter `e` it deletes the previous character.  The letter `r` inserts a tab. I looked at the keyboard shortcuts and don't see anything obvious to change.  I tried using an old Sun keyboard and got the same behavior.   Strangely, when I search the field in the Keyboard Shortcuts field, my `r` and `e` keys work as expected.

Question :
How do I get my `r` and `e` keys to work in my `test.r` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out.  Solution :

`click on gear` -> `Settings` -> `Application` -> `Keyboard` -> `Dispatch` -> change to `keyCode`